# How to use the Central Limit Theorem on two different random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let's say there are 100 independent and identically distributed random variables, $Z_i$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq 100$ and 200 independent and identically distributed random variables, $Y_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq 200$. That is, each $Z_i$ and $Y_j$ are also independent of each other.

I want to use the Central Limit Theorem here to find the 95% percentile of the sum of all these random variables. Since the Central Limit Theorem applies when there are a large number of I.I.D random variables, would it be correct to let $X_i = 2Y + Z$ so that S is just the sum from 1 to 100 of these $X_i$'s? For a concrete example:

A portfolio of policies, all issued at the same time, consisting of the following:

- 200 whole life annuity contracts all issued to (50), each with a payment of \$50 annually
- 100 whole life insurance contracts all issued to (40), each with a death benefit of \$10, payable at the moment of death

The future lifetimes of all policyholders are all independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just say, the sum $S_Z$ of the $Z_i$ is approximately normal with mean $\ldots$ and variance $\ldots$; the sum $S_Y$ of the $Y_j$ is approximately normal with mean $\ldots$ and variance $\ldots$; these two sums are independent, so 
$S_Z + S_Y$ is approximately normal with mean $\ldots$ and variance $\ldots$.

Comment: I was unsure if whether the fact that $S_Z$ and $S_Y$ are both approximately normally distributed would be an issue when claiming that their sum is approximately normal. Thank you for that!